# htaccess generates an 500 internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site (php) which i uploaded to a host and it is unreachable, giving the 500 internal server error message.
I have the same site with the same .htaccess on localhost, and also on 2 other hosts, those are working perfectly.

The server's error message is the following: AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/user/public_html/

This is my .htaccess in the public_html folder (as i said it is the same on 2 other hosts with no problem)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /public_html/

    RewriteRule    ^$    /public/index.php    [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /public/$1    [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If i comment out the

```
RewriteRule    (.*) /public/$1    [QSA,L]
```

line the site loads to the login page, but after i login, it gives 404 error.

The site is php, uses MVC model, redirecting every request to public/index.php

Does anyone have an idea what could go wrong on this host ?

I also have an another .htaccess inside the document_root/public/ folder that is also the same on every host:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this related to PHP, if Apache already throws an error?

Comment: well i asked the host provider, he suggested to comment out that line i mentioned, and that is it. it is only related to php because the site im trying to make work is in php.

Comment: Is that the full error message? Or does it continue with _“No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive”_, as researching the error code suggests would usually be the case?

Comment: AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/user/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php5,index.php4,index.php3,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.wml,Default.h,tml,Default.htm,default.html,default.htm,home.html,home.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `RewriteBase` directive from both `.htaccess` files. In your root `.htaccess` file it is not being used (but is set incorrectly). In the `/public/.htaccess` file the `RewriteBase` is set incorrectly and will end up rewriting requests back to the root (which is presumably not the intention).

Also ensure that the `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly in the `/public/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```